# How to apply a boxcar filter with python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, filter, scipy

I am looking for applying a boxcar filter in order to smooth a radar data.
I read somewhere I should use scipy.signal.boxcar and scipy.signal.convolve, so I looked on [docs.scipy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/) but I don't understand how to do.

Can you help me?

Comment: It would be good to show your attempts on the problem.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I just don't know where to begin. When I go on scipy.signal.boxcar doc, it only gives a way to plot a window with a signal... I don't understand how to apply it on an image.

Comment: Peut-être quelque chose comme ça....                                                 from scipy import signal ____ 
import os ___ 
window = signal.boxcar(7) ___
data = os.path.join(r'G:\path\to\ImageTest.tif') ___ 
filtered = signal.convolve(data, window, mode='same') / sum(window) ___

Comment: Please [edit] your post according to what is described in [ask]. Otherwise, in comments it  is not possible to understand your code.